# Dynamically bond handler on multiple elements will call only last bond function

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/7CV88/8/

On this snippet, I try to bind change to `#r(Nth)e`  `<input>` element to change the contents of `#r(N+1th)s` `<input>` element. But when I change any Nth `<input>` element, the message shown is always "#r(last N)e change handler"

```
for(var i = 1; i < numRanges; i++){
    $('#r'+i+'e').change(function(){
        $('#messages').html('#r'+i+'e change handler');
        $('#r'+(i+1)+'s').val($('#r'+i+'e').val());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the so-called ***event data*** to pass the value of `i` into the `onchange` event handler:

```
for(var i = 1; i < numRanges; i++){
  $('#r'+i+'e').change(i, function(e){
     $('#messages').html('#r'+e.data+'e change handler');
     $('#r'+(e.data+1)+'s').val($('#r'+e.data+'e').val());
  });
}
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/7CV88/9/)

**Note**: This just answers ***directly*** to your asked problem, I know your code is messy, fixing it is not the main thing to do.

Comment: It's the html adding method I'm using or the js approach (or both) that displeases you? I don't have much knowledge on web development analysis, I'm sure many of my approaches to solving problems on this environment are flimsy.

Comment: @Adriano no, in fact it did not displease me at all, I felt totally easy. I just wanted to mean your code has some other things to fix/fine/improve (not just the problem you asked). However I could just fix the problem you asked for, not all the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical "closure" issue.

I was trying the simplest way to get out of the closure issue so I suggested this incorrect way:

```
for(var i = 1; i < numRanges; i++){
    $('#r'+i+'e').change(function(){
        var tempVariable = i;
        $('#messages').html('#r'+tempVariable +'e change handler');
        $('#r'+(tempVariable +1)+'s').val($('#r'+tempVariable +'e').val());
    });
}
```

Thanks to metadings, I realized my mistake so I created a demo to test according to their advice:

```
var list = $("div");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $(list[i]).click((function(x){
        return function(){alert(x);};
    })(i));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qBXn/

HTH

Comment: this won't work, because your `var tempVariable` is in the same function scope as your `var i`. remember: in javaScript, functions are the scope, not like other languages, for example c#, where an if or a for creates a new scope. you need a closure function inside the for.  
`for (var i; ...) { (function (i) { ... })(i); }` this "shadows" the outer `i` with the inner `i`, but that's ok here

Comment: Yeah I was in a hurry but wanted to communicate the general idea. I updated my answer, does this look ok now?

Comment: No it doesn't. hmmm I was thinking the C# way hahah :)